# Is there any way to create a video file directly from GLSurfaceView(OpenGL ES )?

Tags: android, video, opengl-es

I have created a 3D object on GLSurfaceView(OpenGL ES) on android. Is there any way to create a video file (record 5 seconds) directly from GLSurfaceView(OpenGL ES) without screen recording?

Answer (score 2):

You can capture bitmaps after drawing frames and then combine them into a video format.

In `GLSurfaceView.onDrawFrame()` you can use `gl.glReadPixels()` to collect a bitmap image of the frame. You can then pass these to Android's [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) class afterwards to encode them into a final video.